# Can't see git branch in command line

Tags: git

I am trying to push a commit from one branch A to another branch B

So when I use the following command --

```
dev > git push origin dev:staging
```

then it says,

`! [rejected]        dev -> staging (fetch first)`

The problem is that when I do `git branch -a` it doesn't list staging branch.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wants you to do a `git fetch` based on the error.  Maybe somebody else already created a `staging` branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `git push` command says that:

1. Your own Git should call up another Git at the URL stored in your `origin`.
2. Your Git should then offer them the commit identified by your `dev`, and all earlier commits that you have that they don't.  (Run `git rev-parse dev` to see what commit hash ID that is, or `git log dev` to see that commit and all earlier commits reachable from that commit.)
3. After they have those commits saved in some temporary location, your Git should ask their Git to set *their* `staging` to the hash ID used in step 2.

Nowhere in these steps is there any suggestion that *your* Git should do anything with the name `staging` in *your* repository.  You are simply going to ask *them* to do something with the name `staging` in *their* repository.

You could run `git fetch origin` to direct your Git to call up their Git at the same URL.  Your Git will then have their Git list all of their branch names, along with the commit hash IDs that those branch names point to.  For each such commit that you *don't* have, your Git will obtain, from their Git, the commit and any of its earlier commits that *they* have that *you* don't.  When your Git is done obtaining all these new commits, *your* Git will update or even *create* names in *your* repository, to remember *their* branch-tip commit hashes.

The names your Git will use are things like `origin/staging`: your Git will *rename* their branch names, to make your remote-tracking names.  If they have `master`, `dev`, and `staging`, your Git will update or create *your* `origin/master`, `origin/dev`, and `origin/staging`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. I think I have understood.

Answer (score 0):

So, I understand that push is telling you to fetch, and I understand that your local repo doesn't have a `staging` branch... but when you say that's "the problem", that I don't understand.

You said to push your `dev` branch to the remote `staging` branch.  The error indicates that the remote `staging` branch exists and points to a commit that isn't reachable from your `dev` ref - meaning that the update would not be a fast-forward and would be an effective "upstream rebase", possibly losing others' changes and definitely putting all other users of the repo into a bad state from which they'd need to recover.

This does not imply that `staging` should show up in your local repo's list of branches, even with `-a`, because you may have not fetched the `staging` ref from the remote.  If you do a `git fetch`, then after that I would expect `origin/staging` to be included in the output of `git branch -a`.